# How to validate real numbers

Tags: c

I need a form to validate numbers where it only allows the user to enter entire, negative and decimal values. there's a form to make it with this code?

I tried getting the values with the scanf as they where a string of characters, and then, with the function atoi, i convert the resulting string in a number value and then give it to a variable, the problem is that it returns ONLY the entire value, and no decimals, but with negatives there are no problems for some reason, this is the code i have right now following code ACSII:

```
do{ //Entry of data
    printf("introduce a real number: ");
    scanf("%s", chain);
    valid=validate_numbers(chain);
}while(valid==0);

N=atoi(chain);
```

If for example i try to put "34.52" in the program, it should return that exact value to the variable N, but instead it converts the string to "34.00".

https://pastebin.com/J5sk07py here's the entire code btw.

Comment: Why not directly input a float/double through scanf(). IIRC %f is the format code for that.

Comment: @Tanveer. It's more work that way because a mismatched string won't move the file pointer forward, meaning that you will have to jump through hoops to manually extract the bad text.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i` in [`atoi(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/atoi/) means `integer`. That means you're converting your string to an integer, which as you're seeing, doesn't have a fractional part. Use [`strtof(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtof/) or [`strtod(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtod/) to get a `float` or `double` respectively.